# Nontype Template Array

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Is it possible to pass an array as a nontype template argument?

e.g.

```
template<typename T, T> struct s;

template<typename T, size_t S, T A[S]> struct s<T[S], A>
{ };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, here is an example which is valid in C++11 and later:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, size_t S, T A[S]>
struct s
{
    static constexpr auto x = A[1];
};

static constexpr int a[3] = {10,20,30};

int f()
{
    return s<const int, 3, a>::x;
}
```

`f()` returns 20, as seen here: https://godbolt.org/z/GggQd9

For reference, see [the draft C++17 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) §17.1.4.2 [temp.param]:

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,

And §17.1.4.8:

> A non-type template-parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be of type “pointer to T”

The end result being that your `T A[S]` declaration is equivalent to `T* A`, and a pointer to an object is allowed, and arrays are objects, so the code is valid.

Comment: Please note the `language-lawyer` tag.

Comment: @superdeveloper: Is it lawyerly enough now?

Comment: Could you comment on the ability to have a string-literal as a template argument? I know it's outside of the scope of the question